# general class for get current location by gps,network and not connected mode and stop after found

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

of course my question be duplicate. but i can not found good answer for my solution.
i want to write a custom general class that can found current location by location manager and own detect gps enabled or network enabled or use cached and stored locations when device has not gps or network enable. and above all stop work after found first location any way. but i did these works for it : 1- create two locationlistener classes(GPSListener and networkListner):

```
public class GPSListener implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager=null;
public Boolean found=false;
public Location mainLocation=null;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    found=true;
    mainLocation= location;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

---

```
public class NetworkListener implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager=null;
public Boolean found=false;
public Location mainLocation=null;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    found=true;
    mainLocation=location;

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

---

then i use these classes in my activity same this:

```
LatLng result = null;
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    if (DeviceHelper.IsGPSEnabled()) {

        GPSListener gpsListener = new GPSListener();

        // if(gpsListener.found)
        // {
        if (gpsListener.mainLocation != null) {
            ToastHelper.Show(this,
                    "GPS : " + gpsListener.mainLocation.toString());
            gpsListener = null;
            result = new LatLng(gpsListener.mainLocation.getLatitude(),
                    gpsListener.mainLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        // }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsListener);
    }

    else if (DeviceHelper.HasConnect()) {

        NetworkListener netListener = new NetworkListener();

        // if(netListener.found)
        // {
        if (netListener.mainLocation != null) {
            ToastHelper.Show(this,
                    "NETWORK : " + netListener.mainLocation.toString());
            netListener = null;
            result = new LatLng(netListener.mainLocation.getLatitude(),
                    netListener.mainLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        // }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, netListener);
    } else {
        ;
        Location loc = LocationHelper.getLastKnownLoaction(false);
        if (loc != null) {
            ToastHelper.Show(this, "LAST : " + loc.toString());
            result = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        }
    }


    if (result != null) {
        LogHelper.Add("LL", String.valueOf(result.latitude));
        LocationHelper.MyLatLng = result;
        StaticObjects.mainMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(result));
        MapHelper.CameraGo( result, 15);
    } else {
        LogHelper.Add("ERR:", "NULL");
```

### }

i know this not work because manager can not found as a good time before place that i show found location. totally i want to write a general class for finding current location that can stop when found first location.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to write a general class for find my location by gps ,network and disconnect mode and stop manager when a provider found first location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need 2 classes for listening GPS-Glonass and Network updates. You can use just one object as a listener to both providers--since provider can be easily obtained from `Location` object:

```
if(location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    // it is GPS
} else if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
    // it is Network
}
```

Second, to know status of provider(s) you should implement `LocationListener`'s `onStatusChanged()` callback. If a provider is unavailable at the moment you subscribe `LocationListener`, this callback is invoked immediately:

```
 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
     if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) 
         && (status == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE || status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)){
         // gps is unavailable 
     } else if  (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) 
         && (status == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE || status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)){
         // network provider is unavailable 
     }
 }
```

Third, to unsubscribe your object from location updates, use:

```
 locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

this will stop obtaining location updates and shut down GPS-Glonass location service if no other apps need it.

Comment: thanks. when and where  should i use third instruction?

Comment: @PProg when you get first location that satisfy you, just unsubscribe location listener from obtaining more updates.